# Laravel - Filament - Tenant with an extra layer of ownership - uploading documents

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I have set up Filament v3 with multitenancy, and I am using a classic "Team" model. I have one more layer below a team, that I call buckets:

A team can have many buckets, and a bucket can belong to one team.

Then, under a bucket, the user can upload many documents, meaning that: a bucket can have many documents, and a document can belong to one bucket.

Now, I have set up a new resource called `DocumentResource`, but I am simply unable to figure out how I can upload a simple document via a header action, since the document should belong to a bucket, and not to a team directly.

In my `App` panel, I have specified this:

```php
tenant(Team::class, ownershipRelationship: 'bucket')
```

Then, on the `DocumentResource` I have set a relationship:

```php
protected static ?string $model = Document::class;
protected static ?string $tenantRelationshipName = 'buckets';
```

Then, under the `ListDocuments` page, I would like to have the "Upload Document" modal:

```php
protected function getHeaderActions(): array
{
    return [
       Actions\CreateAction::make()
                ->form([
                    FileUpload::make('name')
                        ->required()
                        ->storeFileNamesIn('original_filename')
                ])
    ];
}
```

When I upload, it fails, since Filament is looking for a `team_id` on the `documents`  table. But there is none, only a `bucket_id`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. The way around it is that, I add **team_id** in model Document's $fillable. In ListDocument

```
Actions\CreateAction::make()
    ->form([
        FileUpload::make('name')
           ->required()
           ->storeFileNamesIn('original_filename')
    ])
    ->mutateFormDataUsing(function (array $data): array {
         $data['team_id'] = Filament::getTenant()->id;
         return $data;
    });
```

and you should remove $tenantRelationshipName from youor DocumentResource.